# Difference between 'sed -e' and delimiting multiple commands with semicolon

Tags: sed, posix, options

I am perhaps picking nits here, but it would be really good to have this question that's been bothering me answered once and for all...

Text file for reprex:

```
Line one.
Line two.

Line three.
Line four.
```

To add an additional empty line consistently to this text file would require two `sed` commands for each line. This could be achieved with any of the following syntaxes:

1. `sed -e '/^$/d' -e '$!G' <file>`... but NOT (`sed -e '/^$/d' '$!G' <file>` OR `sed '/^$/d' '$!G' <file>`)
2. `sed -e '/^$/d; $!G' <file>` or `sed -e '/^$/d ; $!G' <file>`
3. `sed '/^$/d; $!G' <file>` or `sed '/^$/d ; $!G' <file>`

My questions are:

1. Is there any real difference (universality?, compliance?...) between any of the five working syntaxes listed above?
2. Richard Blum's Latest [Command Line And Shell Scripting Bible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119700914) says to use something like `sed -e 's/brown/red/; s/dog/cat/' data1.txt` before doling out the following advice...

> The commands must be separated with a semicolon (;), and there
> shouldn't be any spaces between the end of the first command and the
> semicolon.

...and then goes on to completely neglect his own advice by not using the `-e` option at all and also adding spaces between the end of a command and the semicolon (like shown in the second variant of the #3 above).. So, *does the spacing around the semicolon make any real difference, at all*?

3. Although I couldn't find info on this in the manpage or documentation, my hunch is that the `-e` option is meant to be used as shown in syntax number #1 above, and using both `-e` and `;` on the command line is redundant. Am I correct?

---

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned this in my original question to make it more specific; but as some people have already pointed out, these nuances would matter when using branch (`b`) or test (`t`) commands. But it's interesting to note the other cases when these would make a difference. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us use the [Sed POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) to answer the questions.

**Does the spacing around the semicolon make any real difference?**

> Editing commands other than {...}, a, b, c, i, r, t, w, :, and # can be followed by a semicolon, optional blank characters, and another editing command.

Thus `/^$/d ; $!G` is not compliant, but `/^$/d; $!G` is. But I do wonder if
there is any modern Sed implementation that would stumble on that.

**Is there any real difference (universality, compliance...) between any of the three syntaxes listed above?**

No (except for the one with spaces before the semicolon, as argued above).
This is clear in the synopsis:

> ```
> sed [-n] script [file...]  
> sed [-n] -e script [-e script]... [-f script_file]... [file...]
> ```

Do note, however, that as the previous quote mentioned, some commands cannot
be followed by a semicolon, and then

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/x/y/' -e 't a'
```

is compliant, while

```
sed ':a;s/x/y;t a'
```

is not, although but work the same at least in GNU Sed.

**My hunch is that (...) using both `-e` and `;` on the command line is redundant. Am I correct?**

If you refer to the examples in the question, yes. If there is a single `-e`
option, then just drop it and it is all the same (unless you also use the
`-f` option (see the synopsis)). But in

```
sed -e ':a' -e 's/x/y;t a'
```

both `-e` and `;` are present but they are not redundant.

Answer (score 8):

It does matter for a few commands.

In the original `sed` implementations, `: foo;bar`, `b foo;bar`, `t foo;bar` respectively define, branch, conditionally-branch to the `foo;bar` label.

It even used to be required by POSIX (I was the one [asking for the requirement to be relaxed](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=945)).

`w foo;bar` and `r foo;bar` are still to write/read to/from the `foo;bar` file in all conforming implementations.

The `#` command (for comments), `a`, `i`, `c` (append, insert, change) can obviously not be followed by another command on the same line.

Historical `sed` implementations don't support `}` being followed by another command either.

POSIX used to say you couldn't have a `;` before `}` though that wasn't needed in practice (I also [asked for that requirement to be relaxed](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=944)).

```
sed -e cmd1 -e cmd2
```

is meant to be equivalent to

```
sed -e 'cmd1
cmd2'
```

But in practice that's not the case in all implementations when it comes to:

```
sed -e 'a\' -e 'foo\' -e 'bar'
sed -e 's/foo/bar\' -e 'baz/g'
```

for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The benefits seem to be for editing commands.

```
sed -e '/first/a This is cool' -e '/second/i also cool' < <(echo first; echo second)
```

will yield:

```
first
This is cool
also cool
second
```

but attempting

```
sed -e '/first/a This is cool ; /second/i also cool' < <(echo first; echo second)
```

yields

```
first
This is cool ; /second/i also cool
second
```

which obviously interpreted the semicolon as part of the append.  Though you can still achieve this within a single command:

```
sed -e '/first/a This is cool
/second/i also cool' < <(echo first; echo second)
```

Utilizing the hard return to start a new command (allowing script files to play out properly).

Admittedly:

```
sed '
/first/a This is cool
/second/i also cool' < <(echo first; echo second)
```